# Changing BIT XXX on hard drive from 0 to 1

Tags: c++, encryption, storage

i am working on a project to create a encryption by myself.
I know **this will not be secure** and i just want to work with this for my own and **for testing reasons**.

For the basics of the algorythm i will need to change BIT number XY on my HDD from 0 to 1.
The issue is that i don't realy know how to do that. I will use a completly new drive for this project that never had Data on it.

Lets say this drive will be 250GB big and i want to change the first BIT on this drive from 0 to 1, how will i need to do this?
Do i need to create one big file with just 0's in it, or can i directly tell the writing part on the drive that it will need to go to position XY and change the BIT on this position from 0 to 1?

I want to use C++ for this project to archive max speed.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, while running with root, you can literally address the entire drive as a file.  Something like the following to toggle the first bit of a partition.

```
int f = -1;
unsigned char data = 0;

f = open("/dev/hdb1", O_RDWR);
read(f, &data, 1);
data = data ^ 0x80;
lseek(f, SEEK_SET, 0);
write(f, &data, 1);
close(f);
```

Where `/dev/hdb1` might be first partition on the second drive.  You can likely also address `/dev/hdb` for the entire drive itself.

Comment: dosen't `data = data ^ 0x80;` make it a whole byte? if i would write this to bit 1 and then do the same on bit 2, i would overwrite bit numbern 1 or not?

Comment: `data = data ^ x80` toggles the first (high-order) bit in `data` and leaves the other 7 bits unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i decided i will create a file that will contain only `null` bytes.
if i want to change single BIT i will use the following calculation:

```
int bit = XXX; //BIT that will be adjusted
double byte = bit / 8; //Byte that contains BIT
Byte b = getByte( (int)byte ); //save the Byte
b = adjustByte( b, (int)((byte - bit)*8), VALUE ); //adjust the Byte with ASCII symbol
saveByteToFile( b, byte ); //save the Byte back to File to old position
```

This is just pseudo code.
If someone got a better idear how to solve this, pls let me know.

Comment: Don't use a variable of type `double` to compute a byte offset in a file. `bit/8` is an integer expression anyway. Stick with integers.  Your byte offset is `bit/8` as you have it.  But your bit offset within that byte is easily computed as `bit % 8`.  That `(byte - bit)*8` expression makes no sense.  I suspect you need to learn more about integral types and bitwise arithmetic in C to be effective at this.